# SQL help for Query Activity in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I need to calculate a field for a Data Extension based on multiple records in another Data Extension.

**JourneyEntrance** (Data Extension to be updated)

`SubscriberKey`, `PolicyNumber`, `Complete`

**Cases** (Data Extension to reference)

`SubscriberKey`, `PolicyNumber`, `StatusCode`

I need to updated `JourneyEntrance.Complete` field to True if All records in Cases have a `StatusCode` of `E` or `N`. If any `Cases` record has a value other than `E` or `N` then the `JourneyEntrance.Complete` will be `False`. The records are related based on `PolicyNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

I switched it up a little. I think this should work. Haven't tested yet.

```
SELECT  j.SubscriberKey,
        j.PolicyNumber,
        (SELECT COUNT(c.SubscriberKey) FROM Cases c WHERE c.PolicyNumber = 
j.PolicyNumber AND c.StatusCode IN('E','N')) AS CountNotComplete
FROM JourneyEntrance j
```

The thought is once the count reaches 0 then I will know all Cases are Complete.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT JE.SubscriberKey,JE.PolicyNumber,C.StatusCode,     
CASE   
    WHEN (C.StatusCode = 'E' OR C.StatusCode ='N') THEN 'TRUE'  
    ELSE 'FALSE'  
END AS Complete  
FROM [JourneyEntrance] JE  
INNER JOIN [Cases] C  
ON JE.PolicyNumber = C.PolicyNumber
```

Comment: This returns multiple rows  -- one for each Case -- which is not what the OP wanted.